# Connect push button switch to two circuits

Tags: switches

I have a push button switch that is single-pole, that I need to independently control two circuits. The button will be connected to a digital pin of two different microcontrollers. So its a low current application. Unfortunately, in this case, a two-pole button cannot be used. Is there a way of doing this?

Obviously the first that springs to mind is opto-coupling, however, there is a chance that one circuit is not powered, which would mean there is a chance the opto-coupler is not powered.

It cannot be guaranteed that these two circuits share the same power supplies, hence the complications. Technically the two circuits should be +5V, however the grounds aren't necessarily common.

Comment: The button would enable current flow through the diode of the optocoupler, so there is not problem if it is un powered

Comment: You really need to describe your problem if you want a worthwhile answer.     Is this a signal (low current, low voltage) or power (higher current, higher voltage) application. For example it could be a 110 V switch for a light circuit ....or it could be a switch input to a microprocessor at 5 V maximum. Describe your two power domains.

Comment: Added some more information to the original question @JackCreasey. The circuits are both 5V circuits.

Comment: If you don't have either a power supply that is available when either of the two controlled is active or a shared power supply common, you probably can not do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

How about a DPST Relay? Ideally, you'll want the COILVOLTAGE to be one of the voltages you are using for 2 circuits (VCC1, VCC2).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVuRlA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What happens when coilvoltage is 0?

Comment: Nothing useful. The relay just stays open.

Comment: DV for a Page 1 Line 1 error: missing a diode off the relay coil and scorching your switch contacts.

Comment: @TonyM. Small switches are rated for 125 V AC and 12 VDC typically .....and they don't need protection diodes across relays. There will be a spark on breaking the circuit, but it won't impact switch life significantly at all. Certainly not worth a DV.

Comment: @jackcreasey, the arcing will damage the switch contacts and needlessly. No ratings on these switches here. Are you advocating saving a 2p diode to see if you can get away with it? But above that, the schematic is generic and therefore should always clearly show good design practice. Add a diode, I'll scrub the DV,

Comment: @TonyM. It wasn't my answer ....but I do think you were being overly hard with the DV. Coming from a time before computer systems as we know them today....most systems did not use diodes across relays. If a relay was particularly large (high inductance, or high coil current) you might see a snubber, but rarely. The other thing to consider is that putting a diode across a relay delays it's dropout and this can impact some systems (hence the use of Zeners and snubbers instead of diodes).

Comment: Added the protection diode.

Answer (score 0):

A simple diode isolation will work for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYXUEM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's how the circuit is currently done, however I cannot guarantee that both the grounds are at 0V.

Comment: The 0 V level for each system would be connected together by the switch. It does not have to be a true ground terminal. I don't see a way to connect a switch to two system without a zero V reference in each system. For example you could have two battery powered Arduinos ...completely floating from a real ground, but you could connect as above and have the switch work.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. tricky set of conditions...

You can do it with transformers and a function generator to make a fake isolated supply to drive the led of an opto-coupler.

Though if you are willing to detect a modulated signal back you could probably get rid of all that regulator stuff.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFnRnH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Though I am pretty sure there is a way to do this from the primary side, but I cant seem to simulate it.

Or, you can use one of [these](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1572/0900766b81572463.pdf)

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faFySO.png)</sup>